# Enable auto save conversations in Microsoft Office Communicator 2007

Tags: history, office-communicator-2007, autosave

How can I automatically save every conversation that I have in Microsoft Office Communicator 2007?

For any conversation, I have to manually say do the following

1. Click `File`
2. Click `Save`
3. Select `Save As Email`

which saves the Conversation so far in that window to the Conversation History folder. If I forget to do that and close the window, then the conversation is lost. Often the conversation is important for me and there is no way to recover it.

Comment: Not very sure about this, but I believe I used to see the conv. history in outlook 2010 when using communicator 2007 . However I cannot give 100% assurance. And also no clues about how to enable it, can MS exchange experts comment?

Comment: I've had the same issue with MOC 2010 and now Lync 2013. Frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

I think this works only if you have Outlook.

Into Communicator, go to `Tools > Options > Personal > Personal Information Manager` and tick the "Save my instant message conversations in the Outlook Conversation History folder" checkbox.

If the box is greyed out (meaning, disabled by your IT administrators), you have some hackery to workaround in the comments of the [original procedure](http://weblogs.asp.net/coltk/archive/2010/04/29/enable-office-communicator-chat-history-in-outlook.aspx).

If you don't use Outlook, you are bound to your procedure, but I cannot verify.

Comment: In case its disabled for anyone, like on my system, one of the workaround is keyboard shortcut - Shift + F12 in the chat window.

Comment: Can you please summarize the information from the link and include the link as a reference rather than as the answer?

Comment: @Ryan Gates: Done. Very useful since blog post lost its screenshot.

Comment: @akjain: Mark as answer if you think it fits. Your question else will stay in Unanswered state forever.